# make column unique in context of one foreign key entity

Tags: sql, mariadb

So let's image a database scheme for todos. Your todo table would be

- id (PK)
- owner_id (Foreign key on user table)
- title

Of course the `title` column can't be unique because each user can have a todo called "Do this". But one user should not have two todos called "Do this". So `title` is not unique but it is unique for one user (foreign key).

Is there a way I can achieve this by database design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_t_owner_id_title on t(owner_id, title);
```